# JasperReports Passing Parameters

Tags: mysql, jsf, jasper-reports

I have a report in  `JasperReports`, it works fine. However, i'm passing just one parameter of `type` `cliente` to the report, and what i do want now is to pass more than one. The page is like in the picture bellow, a basic idea was to have a button (maybe) that would send the content of `<p:selectOneMenu` that is of the type `cliente` each time its clicked to the `map of parameters`, than it would be sent to the report. I wasn't able to do that yet, so i'm asking for a help.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.model.Cliente;
import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.model.StatusEntrada;
import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.util.jsf.FacesUtil;
import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.util.report.ExecutorRelatorioPdf;
import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.util.report.ExecutorRelatorioXls;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RelatorioEntradasBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Date dataInicio;
    private Date dataFim;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private StatusEntrada statusEntrada;

    public StatusEntrada getStatusEntrada() {
        return statusEntrada;
    }

    public void setStatusEntrada(StatusEntrada statusEntrada) {
        this.statusEntrada = statusEntrada;
    }

    public void teste(StatusEntrada st) {
        // StatusEntrada entrada = StatusEntrada.valueOf(st);
        System.out.println("TESTE: " + st);
    }

    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;

    @Inject
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public void emitirXls() {
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("data_inicio", this.dataInicio);
        parametros.put("data_fim", this.dataFim);
        if (cliente != null) {

            System.out.println("TESTE: " + cliente.getNome());
            parametros.put("nome_cliente", cliente.getNome());
        }
        if (statusEntrada != null) {
            System.out.println("TESTE :" + statusEntrada.getDescricao());
            parametros.put("status_entrada", statusEntrada.getDescricao());

        }

        ExecutorRelatorioXls executor = new ExecutorRelatorioXls("/relatorios/RelatorioEntradasNome.jasper",
                this.response, parametros, "Relatório Entradas.xls");

        Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.doWork(executor);

        if (executor.isRelatorioGerado()) {
            facesContext.responseComplete();
        } else {
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("A execução do relatório não retornou dados.");
        }
    }

    public void emitirPdf() {
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("data_inicio", this.dataInicio);
        parametros.put("data_fim", this.dataFim);
        parametros.put("nome_cliente", this.cliente);

        ExecutorRelatorioPdf executor = new ExecutorRelatorioPdf("/relatorios/RelatorioEntradasNome.jasper",
                this.response, parametros, "Relatório Entradas.pdf");

        Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.doWork(executor);

        if (executor.isRelatorioGerado()) {
            facesContext.responseComplete();
        } else {
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("A execução do relatório não retornou dados.");
        }
    }

    @NotNull
    public Date getDataInicio() {
        return dataInicio;
    }

    public void setDataInicio(Date dataInicio) {
        this.dataInicio = dataInicio;
    }

    @NotNull
    public Date getDataFim() {
        return dataFim;
    }

    public void setDataFim(Date dataFim) {
        this.dataFim = dataFim;
    }

    @NotNull
    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

}
```

Executor:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.jdbc.Work;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter;

public class ExecutorRelatorioXls implements Work {

    private String caminhoRelatorio;
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    private Map<String, Object> parametros;
    private String nomeArquivoSaida;

    private boolean relatorioGerado;

    public ExecutorRelatorioXls(String caminhoRelatorio, HttpServletResponse response, Map<String, Object> parametros,
            String nomeArquivoSaida) {
        this.caminhoRelatorio = caminhoRelatorio;
        this.response = response;
        this.parametros = parametros;
        this.nomeArquivoSaida = nomeArquivoSaida;

        this.parametros.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale("pt", "BR"));
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            InputStream relatorioStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.caminhoRelatorio);

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorioStream, this.parametros, connection);
            this.relatorioGerado = print.getPages().size() > 0;

            if (this.relatorioGerado) {
                JRXlsExporter exportador = new JRXlsExporter();
                exportador.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, response.getOutputStream());
                exportador.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);

                exportador.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
                exportador.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
                exportador.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);

                response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "Cp1256");
                response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + this.nomeArquivoSaida + "\"");

                exportador.exportReport();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Erro ao executar relatório " + this.caminhoRelatorio, e);
        }
    }

    public boolean isRelatorioGerado() {
        return relatorioGerado;
    }

}
```

Query in the report:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     ocorrencia.`id` AS ocorrencia_id,
     ocorrencia.`descricao` AS ocorrencia_descricao,
     ocorrencia.`condicao_tempo` AS ocorrencia_condicao_tempo,
     ocorrencia.`data_ocorrencia` AS ocorrencia_data_ocorrencia,
     ocorrencia.`periodo_ocorrencia` AS ocorrencia_periodo_ocorrencia,
     ocorrencia.`condutor_id` AS ocorrencia_condutor_id,
     condutor.`id` AS condutor_id,
     condutor.`codigo` AS condutor_codigo,
     condutor.`nome` AS condutor_nome,
     entrada_acidente.`id` AS entrada_acidente_id,
     entrada_acidente.`data_criacao` AS entrada_acidente_data_criacao,
     entrada_acidente.`ocorrencia_id` AS entrada_acidente_ocorrencia_id,
     entrada_acidente.`valor_unitario` AS entrada_acidente_valor_unitario,
     cliente.`id` AS cliente_id,
     cliente.`nome` AS cliente_nome,
     entrada_acidente.`status` AS entrada_acidente_status
FROM
     `condutor` condutor INNER JOIN `ocorrencia` ocorrencia ON condutor.`id` = ocorrencia.`condutor_id`
     INNER JOIN `entrada_acidente` entrada_acidente ON ocorrencia.`id` = entrada_acidente.`ocorrencia_id`
     INNER JOIN `cliente` cliente ON entrada_acidente.`cliente_id` = cliente.`id`
WHERE
     entrada_acidente.`data_criacao` BETWEEN $P{data_inicio} AND $P{data_fim}
 AND cliente.`nome` = $P{nome_cliente}
 AND entrada_acidente.`status` = $P{status_entrada}
```

xhtml:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutPadrao.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="titulo">Relatório de entradas emitidas</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="corpo">
        <h:form id="frm">
            <h1>Relatório de entradas emitidas</h1>

            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

            <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:commandButton value="EmitirPdf"
                        action="#{relatorioEntradasBean.emitirPdf}" ajax="false" />
                    <p:commandButton value="EmitirXls"
                        action="#{relatorioEntradasBean.emitirXls}" ajax="false" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <p:panelGrid columns="7" id="painel"
                style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
                <p:outputLabel value="Data de criação" />
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:calendar value="#{relatorioEntradasBean.dataInicio}"
                        label="Data inicial" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" size="8" />
                    <p:spacer width="8" />
                    <h:outputText value="a" />
                    <p:spacer width="8" />
                    <p:calendar value="#{relatorioEntradasBean.dataFim}"
                        label="Data final" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" size="8" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Cliente" for="cliente" />
                    <p:autoComplete id="cliente" size="40" dropdown="true"
                        value="#{relatorioEntradasBean.cliente}"
                        completeMethod="#{cadastroEntradaBean.completarCliente}"
                        var="cliente" itemLabel="#{cliente.nome}" itemValue="#{cliente}"
                        forceSelection="true" />
                </h:panelGroup>


                <p:outputLabel value="Status" />
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="statusEntrada"
                        value="#{relatorioEntradasBean.statusEntrada}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{enumProviderStatus.statusEntradas}"
                            var="statusEntrada" itemValue="#{statusEntrada}"
                            itemLabel="#{statusEntrada.descricao}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: How is this jsf or Primefaces related?

Comment: Thought it was important to mention what is involved into this project besides the `JasperReports` .

Comment: according to your imports, you use cdi, jpa, hibernate, bean validation, servlet and in general Java. So why did you not pick those? Tags in Stackoverflow are not to indicate what you use, but for where your know your problem is

Comment: I'll keep that in mind form now on then thanks.

Comment: Can't really understand, your problem is not on how to pass parameter to jasper report (since you just need to add it in map), right?, your problem is to get it from interface?, how develop interface?

Comment: I am able to get the `cliente` (parameter) from the interface, but, i want to get two (or more)  `clientes` ( two parameters or more) from the interface and then add it to the map. So how do i do that? I know how to add parameters to the map, but not two parameter of the same `type`. So here: `parametros.put("nome_cliente", this.cliente);` i want to add two parameters of the `type` `cliente`. I hope this make it more  clear. And you are right, also how to get get it from interface.